# Javascript percentage calculation for bar width

Tags: javascript, jquery, percentage

I am in need to calculate percentage of current values to attach it to the bars width:

```
<div class="bar"><span class="bar-inside" data-value="120"></span></div>
<div class="bar"><span class="bar-inside" data-value="1320"></span></div>
<div class="bar"><span class="bar-inside" data-value="670"></span></div>
```

I need to find maximum value (in this case it will be 1320) which will be 100% and depending on that calculate other bars width in percentage.

Thank you!

Comment: Can u please create a jsFiddle for us to help

Comment: just loop thru your divs, a get the max value.. then compute the %

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var max = 0;
$('.bar').each(function() {
    max = Math.max(max, $('.bar-inside', this).data('value'));
})
.css('width', function() {
    return ($('.bar-inside', this).data('value') * 100 / max) + '%';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8nmhY/

Comment: Simple and clean. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it: ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DuWUJ/))

```
var max = 0; 

$('.bar-inside').each(function(){ max = Math.max(max, $(this).data("value")); });
```

Comment: should it be $('.bar span') ?

Comment: And how to convert all values to % depending on max one?

Answer (score 1):

use `map` function and then `Math.max`.

```
var values = $.map($("span.bar-inside"), function(el, index) { return parseInt($(el).data('value')); });
var max = Math.max.apply(null, values);
```

above will output `1320` which is expected result.

Answer (score 0):

```
var max = -Infinity;

var maxEle = $(".bar").each(function() {
    if (+this.attr('data-value') > max) +this.attr('data-value', max) ;
}).filter(function() {
    return this.attr('data-value') == max;
});


if (maxEle.length > 1) maxEle = maxEle.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * maxEle.length));
```